# Failed opening 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php'

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, scrutinizer

I've been searching and searching for solutions but I still can't figure out why is this happening. I have another project with the same setup but it doesnt give this error. Runs fine in local but throws error like this in scrutinizer

> Warning Error: include(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   [/home/scrutinizer/build/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php,
>   line 162]
>
> 2018-01-19 07:45:23 Warning: include(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   [/home/scrutinizer/build/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php,
>   line 162]
>
> Warning Error: include(): Failed opening 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/scrutinizer/build:/home/scrutinizer/build/lib:.:/home/scrutinizer/.phpenv/versions/7.1.12/pear:/home/scrutinizer/.phpenv/versions/7.1.12/share/pyrus/.pear/php')
>   in
>   [/home/scrutinizer/build/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php,
>   line 162]
>
> 2018-01-19 07:45:23 Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/scrutinizer/build:/home/scrutinizer/build/lib:.:/home/scrutinizer/.phpenv/versions/7.1.12/pear:/home/scrutinizer/.phpenv/versions/7.1.12/share/pyrus/.pear/php')
>   in
>   [/home/scrutinizer/build/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php,
>   line 162]
>
> ```
> Error: Please install PHPUnit framework v3.7 (http://www.phpunit.de)
> #0 /home/scrutinizer/build/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(218):
> ```

Comment: autoload.php was removed from PHPUnit >= 4, so I'd check that you're using the correct version of PHPUnit and the file exists. If so, check all the include paths in CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php. I'm guessing you're on a newer version of PHPUnit as you're on PHP 7.1.12, and you may need to generate a new autoload.php. If you're still at a loss, check out the documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html

Answer (score -1):

As you already said that you didn't experienced any problem with previous setup.
I suggest you please check the absolute path of the script.

```
/home/scrutinizer/build/lib/Cake/TestSuite
```

I am talking about this path.
and tell if you have solved out the problem.I can't tell more than this as you have provided the error only.If I need to help you more then you should provide more details.
Good luck

Comment: This is not an answer. You're simply telling OP to look in the folder where the error originated...